# Transaction Management in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

My project Structure:

project is in Spring + Hibernate

## Controller -> Service -> DAO

Q.:How can I save data in three tables using the same transaction object ?

If an error occurs during the process saved data must rollback.

I'm currently using three different service methods for saving data in tables from one controller method.

```
@Controller
public @ResponseBody threeSaveMethodsCall(gettingdata data){
  service.saveTableOne(param);
  service.saveTableTwo(param);
  service.saveTableThree(param);
}

@Service
public Boolean saveTableOne(param){
  dao.saveTableOne(param)
}
public Boolean saveTableTwo(param){
  dao.saveTableTwo(param)
}
public Boolean saveTableThree(param){
  dao.saveTableThree(param)
}

@DAO
public Boolean saveTableOne(param){
   Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = sf.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(pojoObj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
                        return false;
        }
        
        return true;
}
public Boolean saveTableTwo(param){
   Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = sf.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(pojoObj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
                        return false;
        }
        
        return true;
} 
public Boolean saveTableThree(param){
   Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = sf.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(pojoObj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
                        return false;
        }
        
        return true;
}
```

I'd like to connect all three transaction in one and if any of the method got an error then the transaction must rollback along with the saved data.

If exists other way for doing it please share it
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Put `@Transactional` on your controller for a single transaction. Other ways depend on the entities and if they have relations

Comment: tableOne, tableTwo, TableThree are connected to each other

Comment: Create a single method on the service that calls the 3 Dao methods. Make that method transactional. ~don't make the web layer the transactional boundary!

Comment: @M.Deinum after doing this no need to beginTransaction in DAO for all three save method?

Comment: Correct. Instead of `openSession` you should be using `getCurrentSession` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's not working.

Comment: What isn't working? If you get errors your tx setup is wrong.